# Vue.js v-for items won't render

Tags: javascript, vue.js

New to Vue js and I'm building my single page app here: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1s5jdc3b/25/). I'm having trouble with my for loop (I believe).

```
const store = {
    items: [{
        todo: 'Clean Apartment.',
    },{
        todo: 'Mow the lawn!',
    },{
        todo: 'Pick up eggs, milk & flour',
    }, {
        todo: 'Watch the big game',
    }],
};

const main = new Vue({
    el: '#vue-todos',
    components: {
        'add-todo': addTodo,
    },
    template: `
        <add-todo></add-todo>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li v-for="item in items">
                    {{ item.todo }}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    `,
    data: store,
});
```

The form (`<add-todo></add-todo>`) renders fine. Why aren't the listed items rendering in the vue template?

Comment: where did you set your `items`?

Comment: @warmjaijai in the `store`. (Edited)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the component in a root element, like below:

```
template: `
        <div>
           <add-todo></add-todo>
            <ul>
                <li v-for="todo in todos">
                    {{ todo.todo }}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    `,
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1s5jdc3b/27/